# Why does alert(navigator.appName) Lock-Up Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

This...

```
alert(navigator.appName);
```

...alerts the browser type in every other browser (google, opera, firefox, IE) but it completely locks-up safari and I have to go in and "end program" to stop it.
 Does any body know why?

here is the whole piece of code...

```
<script language="JavaScript">   
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape")> -1){  
    document.animation.ttt.rows=5;document.animation.ttt.cols=9;}// 
//alert(navigator.appName);
</script>
```

if I comment it out it is fine. If I alert it,  it locks (only in Safari). Crazy?

(edit) updated to latest version... safari 5.0.3 (7533.19.4) no effect on lock up

Comment: Half way throught the page to check something with fonts and then it stop the loading and locks. I know it's that because if I take it out it's fine.

Comment: @gravityboy: Help us help you! Post the code.

Comment: that is the code... if I add that to a page to find out what exact brower name is being used it locks.

Comment: What is the point of testing for Netscape in the appName? More than one browser returns Netscape. Instead use userAgent or better: test for the availability of the stuff you need to manipulate, such as `if (document.animation) ...`

Comment: Yes... all of the browsers that test positive for Netscape get something changed. That's fine. I wanted to see if safari was alerted in that alert because the font was completely different and I wanted to write something specifically for it. But it wouldn't even let me find out what the navigator.appName is. That was the problem and I wanted to know why. That shouldn't lock anything up... correct? p.s I checked alert(navigator.userAgent); and that is locking my safari up also.

Comment: OK step 1: Upgrade from Beta to release. FIVE has been released so no reason to hang about with 4Beta. Step 2. test again

Comment: downloaded and installed (53 megabytes worth) of safari 5.0.3 (7533.19.4) still lockin-up tight as a drum

Comment: Crap, I have to upgrade to SnowLeopard

Comment: Can we have the complete page? Could be a problem with the alert trying to do something while the animation thingy is being resized

Comment: Next day... I put the code at the top of the page and it worked. Then I put it back in original place after the text area resize and it works there now also.

Comment: Great, I am still waiting to receive my SnowLeopard.

Comment: Installed SnowLeopard, then again tried to install Safari 5, but had to upgrade SL first - whew... NOW I can test, but is there any reason to any more?

Comment: @mplungjan see "next day..." comment above. Now I can't even reproduce the problem. So I don't know why it happened or why it stopped.

Comment: I thought so, Thanks. Happy New Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine in my Safari 5.0.3.  Which version are you using? It has to be the code before or after the alert.  For starters check your loops.

Comment: safari 4 public beta (528.16)